# Java is showing that the class is missing

Tags: java

I have this java code which is showing some errors. I don't understand the errors. 
The problem is "I have to take some person name and income one by one & store them in their respective array then I have to calculate their income tax in a method() and print their income tax with their name."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tax {
    int calculateTax(int Income) {

        int num, i;
        String[] arrayOfNames = new String[num];
        Long[] arrayOfIncome = new Long[num];

        int Incometax;
        if (Income >= 300000) {
            Incometax = (Income * 20) / 100;
            System.out.println(arrayOfNames[i] + ": " + Incometax);
        } else if (Income >= 100000 && Income <= 300000) {
            Incometax = (Income * 10) / 100;
            System.out.println(arrayOfNames[i] + ": " + Incometax);
        } else if (Income <= 100000) {
            System.out.println(arrayOfNames[i] + ": No tax" );
        }
        return Incometax;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num, i;
        String Name;
        int Income;


        System.out.println("Enter person count: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] arrayOfNames = new String[num];
        Long[] arrayOfIncome = new Long[num];


        for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {

            System.out.println("Enter name " + (i + 1) + ":");
            arrayOfNames[i] = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter " + arrayOfNames[i] + "'s income: ");
            arrayOfIncome[i] = scanner.nextLong();
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            int Incometax=calculateTax(int Income);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the errors as text into your answer

Comment: Can you, please, edit your post with the errors

Comment: Which line of code is `(47, 56)` then?

Comment: Please add the error messages to your question not as a comment. Also how do you start your programm?

Comment: Error:(47, 56) java: '.class' expected                                                                                         Error:(47, 62) java: ';' expected

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. "Why is this code not working" is not an answer suitable for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

The Op has lot of errors:

1. Method invocation from a static method.
2. Variables are not initialized.
3. Variable declaration.
4. Loop iteration.

So I suggest you to learn some basics and start reading about Java.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things "wrong" and a few things that could be done better.  Comments inline on what needs fixing (this is not fixed code, just pointing out where you need to improve it)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tax {
    /// typically, variables are camel cased (e.g. income instead of Income)
    int calculateTax(int Income) {

        int num, i;
        String[] arrayOfNames = new String[num];
        Long[] arrayOfIncome = new Long[num];

        /// As mentioned, variables should be camel case
        int Incometax;
        if (Income >= 300000) {
            Incometax = (Income * 20) / 100;
            /// At this point, arrayOfNames is empty, so this will error
            System.out.println(arrayOfNames[i] + ": " + Incometax);
        /// the <= 300000 is not needed here, as it will have triggered the first if
        } else if (Income >= 100000 && Income <= 300000) {
            Incometax = (Income * 10) / 100;
            /// At this point, arrayOfNames is empty, so this will error
            System.out.println(arrayOfNames[i] + ": " + Incometax);
        /// This can likely just be an else statement
        } else if (Income <= 100000) {
            /// At this point, arrayOfNames is empty, so this will error
            System.out.println(arrayOfNames[i] + ": No tax" );
        }
        return Incometax;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num, i;
        String Name;
        int Income;


        System.out.println("Enter person count: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] arrayOfNames = new String[num];
        Long[] arrayOfIncome = new Long[num];

            /// ++i increments before evaluation, so this will not work the way you
            /// think it will.  You will likely be one iteration "short"    
        for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            /// i will be incremented before execution, so no need for i+1    
            System.out.println("Enter name " + (i + 1) + ":");
            arrayOfNames[i] = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter " + arrayOfNames[i] + "'s income: ");
            arrayOfIncome[i] = scanner.nextLong();
            System.out.println();
        }
        /// You never use i within this for loop
        for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            /// this will error, as you shouldn't have a type declaration in a method call
            /// Income has already been declared
            /// At this point, Income is 0, as it has not been assigned to.
            int Incometax=calculateTax(int Income);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: It still is the same code, just added a few comments... BTW, value of  the 3rd argument of `for()` (`++i` in this case) is never used, and executed at the end of the loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
int Incometax=calculateTax(int Income);
```

Replace with

```
int Incometax=calculateTax(Income);
```

Also, calculateTax is not static method. So, you cannot call it from static main.

Answer (score -2):

Replace:

```
int Income;
```

with:

```
int income;
```

Only Objects can be named Uppercase.

And

```
calculateTax(int Income);
```

is not right, it should not contain types.

```
calculateTax(Income); // is ok
```